# Activating Remote Desktop Connection on Windows 7 Ultimate Without Sharing Password

Tags: cmd, remote-desktop, elevated-privileges

I'm a student away from home and I need to access my home computer with Remote Desktop Connection. I have a privileged user account on that machine, and I could tell my family to enable RDP, but I don't want them to know my password.

I assume I can make a .reg file to activate RDP, but this could require administrative privilege, which my family's user accounts don't have.

My idea is to send them a script wich they run and RDP gets activated. I would make a batch file and embed it into some Delphi or python executable, just not to store the password in plain text. Security is not a major concern, but I don't want them to look into my documents (they don't know linux live usb or cds).

I tried `echo password&&echo.|runas /user:myusername regedit` to pass it the password but it returns "Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password".

Trying `runas` providing the correct password by hand returns: The requested operation requires elevation.

Someone has an idea?

Comment: Security is not a major concern, but you don't want them to look at your photos and/or videos, right? ;)

Comment: If they know the password in plaintext because I tell them they are a step away from logging into my account, just for curiosity. If I give them an exe and tell them to run it, they just can't imagine what's happening. Besides, really critical stuff is encrypted or not on the computer, and solving my question would probably make me learn something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass your password do `runas.exe` by using SendKeys method in VBScript:

```
Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
oShell.Run "cmd /c runas /user:myusername regedit",1
WScript.Sleep 1000
oShell.SendKeys "mypassword{Enter}"
```

I am sure you can find similar method in Delphi and other programming languages.

And here you can find how to [enable remote desktop by using the registry](http://technet.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/cc782195%28v=ws.10%29.aspx).

Comment: Delphi has a method to simulate key presses, but it's global (like vbs sendkeys), so I will put code to check if the active window is the one I want before sending the keys.

Comment: Tried, but definitely not working. Different command lines tried (with CreateProcess): `runas /user:username "regedit /s setRDP.reg"` (error 740, process requires elevation); `runas /user:username "cmd /c "regedit /s setRDP.reg` not working (a cmd window flashes); `runas /user:username "cmd /c regedit /s setRDP.reg` (same as above); `runas /user:username stage2.bat` where stage2.bat was `regedit setRDP.reg` or `cmd \c regedit setRDP.reg`: not working, with flashy cmd saying only "attempting to start stage2.bat". What a garbage OS

Comment: I also get error 740 when trying to run regedit.exe. But there is also `reg` command that allows for manipulating registry entries from command prompt. And it works with runas: `shell.run "cmd /k runas /user:myusername ""reg import sendkeys.reg""",1

Comment: I gave up after that and phoned them, telling what to do. Things were becoming too difficult and I don't want to waste time trying to do something they didn't think about at Microsoft